# protocol extension use where clause doesn't work in Swift

Tags: swift, where-clause, swift-protocols

We know in Swift, we can use `where` clause in protocol extension:

```swift
    protocol Ordered {
      func precedes(other: Self) -> Bool
    }

    func binarySearch<T: Ordered>(sortedKeys: [T], forKey k: T) -> Int { 11 }

    // I want make all Comparable types confirm Ordered protocol，but compiler complained later...
    extension Ordered where Self: Comparable {
      func precedes(other: Self) -> Bool {
        return self < other
      }
    }

    // ERROR: Global function 'binarySearch(sortedKeys:forKey:)' requires that 'Int' conform to 'Ordered'
    let position = binarySearch(sortedKeys: [2, 3, 5, 7], forKey: 5)
```

Because Int, String, Double, etc. all conform to `Comparable`, So I want perform binarySearch on an array of any `Comparable` type.

But the above code is wrong when compiling. So how to fix that?
Thanks ;)

Comment: Just extend Comparable protocol instead `extension Comparable {` `func precedes(_ other: Self) -> Bool { self < other }` `}`

Answer (score 0):

Adding :

```
extension Int: Ordered { }
```

will fix the compiler error but `Ordered` is redundant with `Comparable`. Why not just declaring :

```
func binarySearch<T: Comparable>(sortedKeys: [T], forKey k: T) -> Int { 11 }
```

?

Comment: Please refer to the following article：https://www.wwdcnotes.com/notes/wwdc15/408/，In the “Retroactive Adaptation” section

Comment: Do you realize that `Int` still needs to conform to `Ordered` if you want to use `binarySearch<T: Ordered>(sortedKeys:)` on an array of `Int` ?

Comment: `Global function 'binarySearch(sortedKeys:forKey:)' requires that 'Int' conform to 'Ordered'` actually that's exactly what the compiler is telling you and that's the first part of my answer

Comment: please refer to [Type Constraints](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Generics.html#ID186)